# error: Found argument '--allow-plugin' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context Did you mean --allow-run?

Tags: permissions, runtime-error, deno

When I try to run my application with the following command, it gives me the following error:

```
deno run --allow-net --allow-write --allow-read --allow-plugin --allow-env --unstable server.ts server.ts
```

> error: Found argument '--allow-plugin' which wasn't expected, or isn't
> valid in this context
> Did you mean --allow-run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `--allow-ffi` instead of `--allow-plugin`.

The permission that was previously named `plugin` is now named `ffi`. See the [permissions list](https://deno.land/manual@v1.14.3/getting_started/permissions#permissions-list) in the manual. You can also read about the change in the [blog post](https://deno.com/blog/v1.13#experimental-ffi-replaces-native-plugin-system) for the release of v`1.13`, or in the [release notes](https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/tag/v1.13.0) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code as you said but I get new error as I wrote in the `EDIT`  part of the question.

Comment: @GoodMan Now that's an entirely different question! See [how to ask on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)